# Django Rest Framework: Sum of serializermethodfields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm having trouble getting this to work.. I have the following Serializer:

```
class OwnArbeitstagListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    stundensumme = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Arbeitstag
        ordering = ['-datum']
        fields = ('id', 'datum', 'in_abrechnung', 'stundensumme')
        depth=0

    def get_stundensumme(self, obj):
        return Stunden.objects.filter(arbeitstagid=obj.id).aggregate(Sum('stunden'))['stunden__sum']
```

.. returning the sum of worked hours per day (The model is named "workday"). That works so far. Now I want to have a ModelViewset returning a list of workdays:

```
class OwnArbeitstagListViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    filter_class = ArbeitstagListFilter
    filter_fields = ('datum',)
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter, filters.SearchFilter,)
    ordering =["-datum"]
    serializer_class = OwnArbeitstagListSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Arbeitstag.objects.filter(userid=self.request.user.id)
```

You see, I'm filtering it by User and by date (with the filterbackend). But now, I want to have an additional field which gives me the sum of the serializermethodfield "stundensumme". Its a sum of a sum. And it should only calculate the sum of the displayed objects (with datefilter applied).

I'm having trouble because (I assume) the Seriealizermethodfield only gets calculated when serializing, and I guess thats to late to get the values for my sum. I have tried this, but it cant find the serializermethodfield "stundensumme" to calculate a sum of:

```
class CustomPageNumberPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    def get_paginated_response(self, data, summe):
        return Response(OrderedDict([
            ('count', self.page.paginator.count),
            ('next', self.get_next_link()),
            ('previous', self.get_previous_link()),
            ('summe', summe),
            ('results', data)
        ]))


class OwnArbeitstagListViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    pagination_class = CustomPageNumberPagination
    filter_class = ArbeitstagListFilter
    filter_fields = ('datum',)
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter, filters.SearchFilter,)
    ordering =["-datum"]
    serializer_class = OwnArbeitstagListSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        arbeitstag = Arbeitstag.objects.all().filter(userid=self.request.user.id)
        return arbeitstag
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        self.summe = queryset.aggregate(Sum('stundensumme'))['stundensumme__sum']
        return super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return self.paginator.get_paginated_response(data, self.summe)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look on `list()` method implementation you will find this:

```
    """
    List a queryset.
    """
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

You are right with your guess that `stundensumme` field only get pouplauted with serialization so you have two options:

1. use [anotate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) and add it in you defiend `get_queryset()` so each object will have that field and you don't need to provide an implementation for the field at serializer and you will just add the field in fields attribute as you did
2. in `get_paginated_response()` do your sum on `data` as it's a list returend by the serializer so you can easily manipulate it for example:

   def get_summe(self, data):

   ```
   sum = 0
   for item in data:
       sum += item['stundensumme']
   return
   ```

and simply use it

```
def get_paginated_response(self, data):
    return Response(OrderedDict([
        ('count', self.page.paginator.count),
        ('next', self.get_next_link()),
        ('previous', self.get_previous_link()),
        ('summe', self.get_summe(data)),
        ('results', data)
    ]))
```

and don't forgot to remove the extra code you added since we don't need it in either two ways